# GULP генериция страниц из шаблона

Tags: gulp

Коллеги, всем привет.

Имею довольно эпизодический опыт работы с GULP. Подскажите плиз как решить задачку.

Крайне утрированный пример, для простоты понимания и краткости ответа.

В gulpfile.js есть масивчик.

```
const clients = [
  {name: 'Супер фирма', desсription: 'Это самая лучшая фирма', path: 'company1' },
  {name: 'Просто фирма', desсription: 'Это отличная фирма', path: 'company2' },
  {name: 'Плохая фирма', desсription: 'Это просто фирма', path: 'company3' },
];
```

Есть в проекте html файл `./src/templates/_company.html`, что-то типа

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>@@name</h1>
    <div>@@desсription</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Хочется сделать такой `gulp.task` чтоб после его выполнения в сборке появились три файла заполненные соответственно JS массиву

```
./dist/company1/index.html
./dist/company2/index.html
./dist/company3/index.html
```

Может есть плагин какой который так умеет?
Спасибо за ответ.